# Эффект hover на append элемента в jQuery

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте.

Возникла трудность с hover'OM с элементом, который добавлен с помощью append.

```
$(".filmGenre").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $(this).css("border", "2px blue solid");
        $("#listFilm #" + id + ".filmGenre .block").css("opacity", "1").show();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $(this).css("border", "0px blue solid");
        $("#listFilm #" + id + ".filmGenre .block").css("opacity", "0").hide();
    }
});
```

Работает только с "реальными элементами". Просьба подсказать. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Можете добавить минимальный пример на http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JSqv5/

Answer (score 3):

Используйте делегирование. Не знаю вашу структуру, но вам надо событие повесить на родителя элемента с классом "**filmGenre**". [Посмотрите этот пример.](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/WaNGb/) Теоретически, родителем может быть даже **body**, но в крайности впадать не надо ))

Вот ваш [подкорректированный пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/JSqv5/1/)